# Nested generic record

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-10.1-berlin, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I just faced a strange compiler error when trying to define nested generic record.

Nesting works fine with classes and interfaces, but not with records somehow.

```
type
  TRec<T> = record
    Value: T;
  end;

  TCls = class
  public
    Rec: TRec<TRec<Integer>>;
  end;
```

This is not compiled on *Delphi Berlin 10.1.2* and also no luck on *Tokyo 10.2.3*. Is this a limitation of language or a compiler issue?

The error message is:

> [dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(22): E2564 Undefined type 'TRec<T>'

I just wanted once to nest the `Spring.Nullable<>` types and that did not work. After that I quickly reproduced that with a simple generic record.

Comment: Is this working for you: `TCls = class
  private
    type
      Trec1<T1> = record Value : T1; end;
  public
    Rec: TRec<TRec1<Integer>>;
  end;`

Comment: @LURD: Nope. Same error.

Comment: Hmm, at least it compiles in my Delphi 10.2 Tokyo update 2.

Comment: @LURD That does compile fine, in all Delphi versions. Pretty sure that asker didn't compile your code, and misread your comment. I also found that same workaround independently.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

type
  TCls = class private type Trec1<T1> = record Value : T1; end; public Rec: TRec<TRec1<Integer>>; end;

begin
end.
Error: [dcc32 Error] Project84.dpr(8): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TRec<>'

Comment: on Berlin 10.1 update 2. 24.0.25048.9432.

Comment: @Z.B. Well, you didn't define `TRec` did you! LURD is proposing the exact same workaround as can be found in my answer.

Comment: Same on Tokyo 10.2 Update 3 (25.0.29899.2631)

Comment: oh.. I see :) I just copied LURD code and tried and by error assumed it's the same issue. Excuse me both please.

Comment: Does it work with an intermediate `TRecInteger = TRec<Integer>;` and later, in the class: `Rec: TRec<TRecInteger>;`? I can't test this (no Delphi here), but I guess it compiles. That is the first thing I would try.

Comment: No, that does not compile either. Not even using an intermediate `TRecRecInteger = TRec<TRecInteger>;` does, nor does making the class generic `TCls<T> = class`.

Answer (score 9):

This is a compiler bug, and you should submit a bug report. Consider the following:

```
type
  TRec<T> = record
    Value: T;
  end;

var
  Rec: TRec<TRec<Integer>>; // compiles successfully
  RecArray: TArray<TRec<TRec<Integer>>>; // compiles successfully

procedure foo;
var
  Rec: TRec<TRec<Integer>>; // compiles successfully
begin
end;

type
  TContainingClass = class
    Rec: TRec<TRec<Integer>>; // E2564 Undefined type 'TRec<T>'
  end;

  TContainingRecord = record
    Rec: TRec<TRec<Integer>>; // E2564 Undefined type 'TRec<T>'
  end;

  TContainingObject = object
    Rec: TRec<TRec<Integer>>; // E2564 Undefined type 'TRec<T>'
  end;
```

The defect appears to arise when using the type inside an aggregate compound type.

It's somewhat lame, but this is the only workaround I can find:

```
type
  TRec<T> = record
    Value: T;
  end;

  TRecRec<T> = record
    Value: TRec<T>;
  end;

  TContainingClass = class
    Rec: TRecRec<Integer>;
  end;
```

But that's not going to be at all useful in any real world scenario.

Comment: Let's hope Idera will fix this. Otherwise sometimes it can be nasty limitation to define each time you want to nest a separate record type. Thanks for your time, David.

Comment: Idera won't, but perhaps Embarcadero will fix it. It is still Embarcadero Delphi.

Comment: Can't check this right now, but what if you have `Unit1.TRec<Unit1.TRec<Integer>>` as the type inside the class/record/object declaration (Assuming `Unit1` is the unit name in which `TRec` is defined)?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis E2564 Undefined type 'TRec<T>'

Comment: @Z.B. They won't fix it if it's not reported - please do or let me know and I do.

Comment: @David: thanks. That is indeed weird, or wrong, or a bug, depending on your POV.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you report that? As the licensing and login info is on the company management side and I have no access to quality portal.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. You don't need licensing information to be able to submit a bug report.

Comment: @Z.B.: everyone can report and everyone can access QP, if you have a (free) EDN login.

Comment: Reminds me of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639444/327083).  Emba seems to stumble frequently with self reference.